# How to get the dropbox icon back without removing Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, dropbox

I installed the newest Chrome-version (38). Before that I was using version 34 and the dropbox indicater was in the system tray. After installing Chrome after restarting a message showed up indicating that an additional library had to be installed (libappindicator1). Unfortunately this removed Chrome.

I re-installed Chrome and the problem appeared again. When I manually tried to install libappindicater1 (sudo apt-get install libappindicator1) there indeed is a warning that Chrome will be removed (it's in Dutch).

De volgende pakketten zullen VERWIJDERD worden:
 google-chrome-stable:i386 libappindicator1:i386 libindicator7:i386

Dropbox seems to be working fine but how can I get the icon back without removing Chrome?

Someone else had this problem and fixed it with a new install but re-installing Ubuntu is no option for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you aren't trying to mix up 64bit and 32bit software? I have Dropbox, Chrome and libappindicator1 installed correctly, with amd64 (64bit) architecture. I would say you need everything 64bit (unless on an older system). From the error, it looks like the installed version of chrome is 32 bit. So try to download the "64bit .deb" version from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/.

This should hopefully be compatible with your Dropbox (make sure that too is 64bit).

btw you can check the version and architecture of a library with

```
dpkg-query -i lib*indicator*
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. After installing the 64-bit version it was fixed. Thanks!